# Alter Regex to match reverse string

Tags: php, regex

I have regex: `\\([A-Z][\w]+::)` which matches the strings `\CustomLib::get...`or  `\Resize::get...` or `\Models::get...`, that could be other similar strings as well.

I want to alter regex: `\\([A-Z][\w]+::)` to get list string instances which does not have leading backslash like `CustomLib::get...`or  `Resize::get...` or `Models::get...`.

Comment: Are you looking for specific `CustomLib` or other strings as well? If you have a list of strings - add them. Otherwise - what is the nature of these strings?

Comment: That could be other strings as well similar to this, but same case applicable to those strings as well where to identify string has leading backslash or not.

Comment: @Dekel Can you please share your input?

Comment: Maybe `(?<!\\)\b[A-Z]\w+::`?

Comment: Any feedback? What is your programming language?

Comment: @Dekel Thank you. That does worked by doing minor trick. I am happy to mark this as accepted answer.
Wiktor, it's PHP.

Comment: So, `'~(?<!\\\\)\b[A-Z]\w+::~'`, right? I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to match the substrings if they are not preceded with a backslash.

Use a [*negative lookbehind*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?<!\\)`:

```
'~(?<!\\\\)\b[A-Z]\w+::~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gHT9ka/1)

Note that in case you may have escape entities in your input, you will need to account for literal backslashes, and use

```
'~(?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\\\\\)*\b([A-Z]\w+)::~'
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gHT9ka/2).